# webexception unhandled by usercode, ioexception-the device is not ready when viewing pdf or image file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a code which reads the pdfpath and displays in the new popupwindow, 
here is my code

```
string path = Request.QueryString["val"].ToString();
string extention = Path.GetExtension(path);
int len = extention.Length - 1;
string extwithoutdot = extention.Substring(1, len);

if (extwithoutdot.Equals("JPG") || 
    extwithoutdot.Equals("jpg") || 
    extwithoutdot.Equals("jpeg") || 
    extwithoutdot.Equals("JPEG"))
{
    extwithoutdot = "jpeg";
}
if (extwithoutdot.Equals("TIF") || extwithoutdot.Equals("tif"))
{
    extwithoutdot = "tiff";
}
if (extwithoutdot.Equals("GIF") || extwithoutdot.Equals("gif"))
{
    extwithoutdot = "gif";
}
if (extwithoutdot.Equals("BMP") || extwithoutdot.Equals("bmp"))
{
    extwithoutdot = "bmp";
}



string filetype = "";
if (extention.Equals(".pdf") || extention.Equals(".PDF"))
{
    extwithoutdot = "pdf";
    filetype = "PDF";
}

WebClient client = new WebClient();
//driveInfo.IsReady;
Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(path);
```

am getting the error as device is not ready
how to resolve this issue?

Comment: First, on which line is the exception? Second, what is the value for `path`?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of code missing, is there any stream that starts reading that you've forgotten to close for example?

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question (as in it's current state, it's impossible for us to diagnose the problem), but your code is bugging me! Your `if` statements are horribly inefficient and could be rewritten with a nice `switch` block instead:

```
//First make the string lowercase:
string extwithoutdot = extention.Substring(1, len).ToLower();

switch(extwithoutdot)
{
    case "jpg":
        extwithoutdot = "jpeg";
        break;

    case "tif":
        extwithoutdot = "tiff";
        break;

    default:
        //Don't need to do anything
}
```